# Troubleshooting HAProxy Access Issue in Docker-Compose Setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, haproxy

I'm new to Docker and have been trying to get a simple docker-compose setup working However, I'm facing an issue:
although I can directly access the web application on the exposed port 82, I can't seem to reach it via HAProxy on the exposed port 81. I'm currently using Docker version 25.0.3.
Can anyone help me figure out what I might be missing in my configuration?

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    image: httpd
    ports:
     - 82:80

   lb:
     image: 'dockercloud/haproxy:latest'
     volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     links:
       - webapp
     ports:
      - 81:80
```

Comment: What happens if you try to connect to it?  Are you sure the process inside the container is listening on 0.0.0.0:80?  (It shouldn't make a difference here, but consider removing the obsolete `links:` option.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, I get browser error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE , I checked the web application log and yes it's listening on http://[::]:80, I tried using networks and got the same result

Comment: What's your haproxy  config?

Answer (score 4):

Your setup looks like this:

```
       Internet
           |
          [81]
       HAProxy
           |
          [80]
        Web App
           |
          [82]
```

- Requests come in on port 81 (HAProxy), which should then forward them to the web application listening on port 80 inside its container.
- The web app container maps port 80 internally to port 82 externally.

Try the following `docker-compose.yml` file for a proper networking and communication between the `webapp` and `lb` services:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - 82:80
    networks:
      - webnet

  lb:
    image: 'dockercloud/haproxy:latest'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 81:80
    depends_on:
      - webapp
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

As suggested, the [`links:` option is obsolete](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) and not necessary for modern Docker networking. Containers in the same network can discover and communicate with each other by service names.

This defines a custom network `webnet` and assigned both services to it. That makes sure they can communicate using the service name as the hostname.
Make sure your HAProxy configuration within the [`dockercloud/haproxy`](https://hub.docker.com/r/dockercloud/haproxy/tags) container is correctly set up to route traffic to the `webapp` service. HAProxy needs to know the correct service name and port to forward requests appropriately.

```bash
docker exec -it [container_id_or_name] /bin/sh
cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
...
# you should see a backend section like:
backend http_back
    balance roundrobin
    server webapp webapp:80 check
```

And check that HAProxy is configured to listen on `0.0.0.0:80` or `*:80` to make sure it accepts connections from all IP addresses, at least for testing.

---

> Still not working, but when I checked `haproxy.cfg` `backend` section, it looks like this:
>
> ```
> backend app 
> balance roundrobin 
> server app1 127.0.0.1:5001 check 
> server app2 127.0.0.1:5002 check 
> server app3 127.0.0.1:5003 
> check server app4 127.0.0.1:5004 check
> ```
>
> and no other containers are currently active
>
> I tried to use port 5001 instead of 81, but still no luck

If auto-discovery is failing and you have specific routing needs, consider manually specifying your HAProxy configuration. You can mount a custom `haproxy.cfg` file into a standard HAProxy container, replacing `dockercloud/haproxy` for debugging purposes:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    image: httpd
    networks:
      - webnet

  haproxy:
    image: haproxy:latest
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

In `haproxy.cfg`, explicitly define the backend to point to your `webapp` service, making sure it matches the service name and port within the Docker network:

```
backend webapp_backend
    balance roundrobin
    server webapp webapp:80 check
```

---

> But this eliminates mounting `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`, which makes it possible for HAProxy to interact with the Docker daemon to inspect and list running containers, without it, I have to set every running container manually.

Then make sure all your containers (especially the `webapp` service) have the correct labels that `dockercloud/haproxy` expects for auto-discovery. And check the logs of the HAProxy container for any errors or warnings that might indicate why it is not correctly identifying and configuring backends based on the running containers. ()`docker logs [haproxy-container-id]` to check the logs).

If the auto-discovery feature is not working as expected with the `dockercloud/haproxy` image, consider two alternatives:

- Extend the `dockercloud/haproxy` image with a custom Dockerfile, where you can adjust or replace the startup script to better handle your discovery requirements or fix issues with the current discovery mechanism.
- Or, switch to another dynamic HAProxy docker image: there are other HAProxy Docker images or third-party solutions designed to work with Docker and provide dynamic backend discovery. These might offer more flexibility or compatibility with your specific Docker setup.

As a compromise between fully manual configuration and dynamic auto-discovery, you can use a simple automation script that updates the HAProxy configuration based on the current state of running containers. That would involve:

- writing a script that uses Docker CLI commands (e.g., `docker container ls`) to discover running containers and generate an HAProxy configuration file based on this information.
- scheduling the script at regular intervals or triggering it based on specific events (e.g., container start/stop) to keep the HAProxy configuration updated.

If you are running in a more complex environment and need robust service discovery and load balancing, consider Docker Swarm Mode, or even Kubernetes.

Comment: Still not working, but when I checked haproxy.cfg backend section it looks like this
backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:5001 check
    server  app2 127.0.0.1:5002 check
    server  app3 127.0.0.1:5003 check
    server  app4 127.0.0.1:5004 check


and no other containers are currently active

Comment: I tried to use port 5001 instead of 81, but still no luck

Comment: thank your for your update but this eliminates mounting 
/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
which make it possible for haproxy to interact with the Docker daemon to inspect and list running containers, without it I have to  set every running container manually

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some issues with your docker file.

1. `links` is no more used and is dropped by dockers now `depends_on` is to be used.
2. Your docker should look something as below

```
services:
  webapp:
    image: httpd
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  lb:
    image: haproxy:latest
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork
```

Additionally you may be required to use a custom `haproxy.cfg`

```
backend webapp_backend
    balance roundrobin
    server webapp webapp:80 check
```